# Marketo Email Template Validation Error: "document type does not allow element "table" here"

Tags: html, email, templates, marketo

I am trying to customize a Marketo template template out for a client but I am getting some validation errors when I tried to add a table on top of the main content box. I'm extremely new at this could I get some expertise on a solution?

```
Error Message:
    line 104 column 4 - Warning: missing <tr>
    line 104 column 4 - Warning: discarding unexpected <table>
    line 105 column 19 - Warning: missing <td>
    line 139 column 4 - Warning: <tr> isn't allowed in <body> elements
    line 63 column 1 - Info: <body> previously mentioned
    line 139 column 4 - Warning: inserting implicit <table>
Html:
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
<title>Auteur</title>
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px)
{
    *[class].inner_table
    {
        width:400px !important;
    }
    *[class].device_tables
    {
        width:440px !important;
    }
    *[class].padd_iphone
    {
        padding-left:21px !important;
        padding-right:21px !important;
    }
    *[class].center_pad
    {
        text-align:center !important;
        padding-bottom:17px !important;
    }
    *[class].padd_left
    {
        padding-left:20px !important;
    }
    *[class].more_hgt
    {
        height:40px !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 475px) 
{
    *[class].inner_table
    {
        width:100% !important;
    }

    *[class].device_tables
    {
        width:300px !important;
    }
    *[class].tab_wide
    {
        width:277px !important;
    }
    *[class].more_hgt
    {
        height:40px !important;
    }


}
</style>
</head>

<body class="bodymain" style="margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:10px 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none; background:#ffffff;">
<table  class="device_tables" style="margin:0 auto;border:0px solid #CCCCCC; border-collapse:collapse; width:600px; " width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
<!--header row-->
<tr>
 <td  style="border:1px solid #FFFFFF;background-color:#FFFFFF;">
 <table  width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
  <!--extra height row-->
    <tr>
        <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:0px; height:18px; background-color:#FFF;" height="0">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <!--logo and nav row-->
    <tr>
        <td class="padd_iphone">
           <!--header table-->
           <table class="inner_table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="562" style="margin:0 auto; width:562px;">
           <tr>
               <!--logo-->
               <td align="left" style="padding-right:40px;">
                 <div class="mktEditable" id="auteur_logo" style="overflow:hidden;">
                  <img  src="http://pages.safebuilt.com/rs/345-JUY-926/images/Logo.jpg" style="border:none;" alt="Meritage-logo" />
                  </div>
               </td>
               <!--nav-->
               <td style="line-height:1px; padding-right:1px;vertical-align:middle;" align="right" >
               <div class="mktEditable" id="auteur_social" style="overflow:hidden;">
              <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://pages.safebuilt.com/rs/safebuilt/images/EM-auteur-v1_facebook.png" border="0"  alt="facebook" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://pages.safebuilt.com/rs/safebuilt/images/EM-auteur-v1_utube.png" border="0"  alt="youtube" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://pages.safebuilt.com/rs/safebuilt/images/EM-auteur-v1_linkedin.png" border="0"  alt="linkedin" /></a>&nbsp;
               </div>
               </td>
           </tr>
           </table> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!--extra height-->
    <tr>
        <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; height:0px;  background-color:#ffffff;" height="18">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>

    <!--Full Row -->
   <table class="inner_table" width="590px" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="padd_iphone" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:25px; font-weight: 100; color:#b22029; text-align:left;">
                    <div class="mktEditable" style="overflow:hidden; padding-top: 40px;">

                      Hello from your friendly Design Sherpas, 
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                    <!--extra height-->
                    <tr>
                        <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; height:14px;  " height="14">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="padd_iphone" style="text-align:left; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight: 100; color:#000; line-height:22px; padding-right:20px;" align="left">
                     <div class="mktEditable" style="overflow:hidden;">
                        Morbi pulvinar elit vitae rhoncus ullamcorper
                        Curabitur scelerisque vehicula mi, a lobortis
                        lectus eleifend id. Vivamus sollicitudin mattis
                        augue ut maximus. Nunc vehicula purus.Vivamus sollicitudin mattis
                        augue ut maximusVivamus sollicitudin mattis
                        augue ut 
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <!--extra height-->
                  <tr>
                    <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; height:20px;  " height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="padd_iphone">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<!--iphone column row-->
   <tr>
       <td>
          <table class="inner_table" width="588" style="margin:0 auto; width:588px;" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
             <tr>
               <td>
               <!--iphone banner-->
                  <table class="inner_table" width="43%" align="left" style="text-align:left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                   <tr>
                   <td class="center_pad" style="padding-top:3px;">
                     <div class="mktEditable" id="phone_banner" style="overflow:hidden;">
                      <img alt="iphone-banner" src="http://pages.safebuilt.com/rs/345-JUY-926/images/White_Left.png" border="0" style="border:none;" />
                     </div>
                   </td>
                   </tr>
                  </table>
                <!--right section-->
                <table class="inner_table" width="53%" align="right" style="text-align:right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="padd_iphone" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:25px; font-weight: 100; color:#b22029; text-align:left;">
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="right_header" style="overflow:hidden; padding-top: 0px;">

                      How awesome is Meritage Systems?, 
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                    <!--extra height-->
                    <tr>
                        <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; height:14px;  " height="14">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="padd_iphone" style="text-align:left; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight: 100; color:#000; line-height:22px; padding-right:20px;" align="left">
                     <div class="mktEditable" id="right_text" style="overflow:hidden;">
                        Morbi pulvinar elit vitae rhoncus ullamcorper
                        Curabitur scelerisque vehicula mi, a lobortis
                        lectus eleifend id. Vivamus sollicitudin mattis
                        augue ut maximus. Nunc vehicula purus.Morbi pulvinar elit vitae rhoncus ullamcorper
                        Curabitur scelerisque vehicula mi, a lobortis
                        lectus eleifend id. Vivamus sollicitudin mattis
                        augue ut maximus. Nunc vehicula purus.
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <!--extra height-->
                  <tr>
                    <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; height:20px;  " height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="padd_iphone">
                        <!--icon text table-->
                        <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="text-align:left;">
                          <!--first row-->
                           <tr>
                             <td valign="top" style="vertical-align:top; padding-top:2px;">
                             <div class="mktEditable" id="iconfirst" style="overflow:hidden;">
                               <img style="border:none;" alt="icon1" src="http://pages.safebuilt.com/rs/safebuilt/images/EM-auteur-v1_icon_1.jpg" />
                               </div>
                              </td>
                              <!--extra width cell-->
                              <td width="13" style="width:13px">&nbsp;

                              </td>
                              <td >
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="left" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#000; ">
                                  <div class="mktEditable" id="boldtxt1" style="overflow:hidden;">
                                  Utenim Adminim Veniam
                                  </div>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <!--extra height-->
                                <tr>
                                  <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; height:5px;  " height="5">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                  <td align="left" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000;">
                                  <div class="mktEditable" id="regulartxt1" style="overflow:hidden; line-height:18px;">
                                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec
                                    adipiscing elit aliquam diam quam.
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <!--extra height-->
                           <tr>
                              <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; height:20px;  " height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                           </tr>
                           <!--second row-->
                           <tr>
                             <td valign="top" style="vertical-align:top; padding-top:3px;">
                             <div class="mktEditable" id="iconsecond" style="overflow:hidden;">
                               <img style="border:none;" alt="icon1" src="http://pages.safebuilt.com/rs/safebuilt/images/EM-auteur-v1_icon_2.jpg" />
                               </div>
                              </td>
                              <!--extra width cell-->
                              <td width="13" style="width:13px">&nbsp;

                              </td>
                              <td >
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="left" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#000; ">
                                  <div class="mktEditable" id="boldtxt2" style="overflow:hidden;">
                                  Persiciatis Unde Quiater
                                  </div>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <!--extra height-->
                                <tr>
                                  <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; height:5px;  " height="5">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                  <td align="left" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000; padding-right: 10px; line-height:18px;">
                                  <div class="mktEditable" id="regulartxt2" style="overflow:hidden;">
                                  Sit aspernatur aut odit aut wue fugit 
                                    sed quia magni amet dolores.
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                            <!--extra height-->
                           <tr>
                              <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; height:20px;  " height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                           </tr>
                           <!--third row-->
                           <tr>
                             <td valign="top" style="vertical-align:top; padding-top:3px;">
                              <div class="mktEditable" id="iconthird" style="overflow:hidden;">
                               <img style="border:none;" alt="icon1" src="http://pages.safebuilt.com/rs/safebuilt/images/EM-auteur-v1_icon_3.jpg" />
                               </div>
                              </td>
                              <!--extra width cell-->
                              <td width="13" style="width:13px">&nbsp;

                              </td>
                              <td>
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="left" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#000;  ">
                                  <div class="mktEditable" id="boldtxt3" style="overflow:hidden;">
                                  Dolorem Magna Aliqua
                                  </div>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <!--extra height-->
                                <tr>
                                  <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; height:5px;  " height="5">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                  <td align="left" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000; line-height:20px;padding-right:10px;">
                                  <div class="mktEditable" id="regulartxt3" style="overflow:hidden; ">
                                  Phasellus tempus turpis vel tempor
                                      euismod duis ullamcorper tincidunt
                                    odio id egestas est.
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                   <!--extra height-->
                   <tr>
                       <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; height:26px;  " height="26">&nbsp;</td>
                   </tr>

                   <!--red green button row-->
                   <tr>
                      <td >
                         <table class="tab_wide" align="left"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="261" style="width:261px; text-align:left ">
                         <tr>
                            <td class="padd_left" align="left">
                            <div class="mktEditable" id="red_button" style="overflow:hidden;">
                               <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><img style="border:none;" alt="red-link" src="http://pages.safebuilt.com/rs/safebuilt/images/EM-auteur-v1_red_btn.jpg" /></a>
                               </div>
                            </td>
                             <!--extra width cell-->
                              <td width="8" style="width:8px">&nbsp;
                               </td>
                             <td align="left">
                            <div class="mktEditable" id="green_button" style="overflow:hidden;">
                               <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><img style="border:none;" alt="green-link" src="http://pages.safebuilt.com/rs/safebuilt/images/EM-auteur-v1_green_btn.jpg" /></a>
                               </div>
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                         </table>
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                  </table>
                  <!--right section ends-->
               </td>
             </tr>

          </table>
          <!--588px table ends-->
       </td>
   </tr>
   <!--extra height-->
   <tr>
       <td class="more_hgt" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; height:48px;  " height="48">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>


   <!--footer-->
   <tr>
       <td style="border-top:1px solid #ccc; background-color:#F5F5F5;">
          <table class="inner_table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center" style="margin:0 auto;">
          <tr>
           <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; height:19px;  " height="19">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; text-align:center; color:#000;" >
              <div class="mktEditable" id="footer_txt" style="overflow:hidden;">
              Copyright &copy; 2014. All rights Reserved 
              </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; height:19px;  "    height="19">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error messages indicate that you are trying to insert a table inside an html element that won't accept it. Including your entire html file here is not useful because it does not indicate the general area of the problem.

Are you using a visual editor, or hand-editing your html? Visual editors can guard you against many errors of this type, though by no means all. If you are hand-editing your html, or if you want to get a better sense of what works and what doesn't, [W3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) provides excellent free HTML tutorials and documentation.